# UITableView SectionIndexTitlesForTableView not split?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

plz need some help here the Section IndexTitles doesn't split? it's looks like in image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `numberOfRowsInSection:`. You need to have a data structure that is an array of arrays. The outer array should have one entry for each section. The inner array would have the rows for the section.

Then it would be like:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSArray *rowData = listData[section];

    return rowData.count;
}
```

Of course you need to update other table view data source methods to deal with this updated data structure.

Comment: thanks but the app crashes and i get this:
NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 24 beyond bounds [0 .. 8]'

Comment: Have you refactored your data structures as I mentioned?

Comment: Yes i did. after i change the return [listData count]; to NSArray *rowData = listData[section]; return rowData.count; then give me that message.

Comment: You don't understand. You need to redo how you setup your data structures in viewDidLoad. You need to create an array of arrays.

Comment: i really don't understand! do you mean i should great another array instead of NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E",@"F",@"G",@"H",@"I", nil]; ??

Comment: Your data needs to be organized by section. The "A" section should have an array representing the rows that appear in section "A". The "B" section should have an array representing the rows that appear in section "B", etc. As I've said before, you need an array of arrays.

Comment: Have a look at the "TableViewSuite" sample app from Apple. The "SimpleIndexedTableView" shows an example of this.